# Swift - Risk in using autoreleasepool? CPU usage?

Tags: swift, nsautoreleasepool

With the Xcode Profiler I have just spotted a not really necessary memory peak on JSON decoding. Apparently it's a known issue and I should wrap the call in an `autoreleasepool` which helped:

```
//extension..
var jsonData: Data? {
    return autoreleasepool{ try? JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: self, options: []) }
}
```

I found another few big chunks of allocations that were not really needed so I applied my newly-learned trick to other code as well, such as the following:

```
var protoArray = [Proto_Bit]()

for bit in data {
    
    autoreleasepool{

        if let str = bit.toJSONString() {
            if let proto = try? Proto_Bit(jsonString: str) {
                protoArray.append(proto)
            }
        }
                    
    }
    
}
```

Now, before I wrap every single instruction of my code (or at least wherever I see fit) in this `autoreleasepool` thing, I would like to ask if there are any risks or drawbacks associated to it.

With these two wraps I was able to reduce my peak memory consumption from 500mb to 170mb. I am aware that Swift also does these kinds of things behind the scenes and probably has some guards in place however I would rather be safe than sorry.

- does `autoreleasepool` come with a CPU overhead? If it is 5% I would be okay with that since it sounds like a good tradeoff, if it's more I would have to investigate
- can I mess up anything using `autoreleasepool`? Null pointers, thread locking etc. since the block structure looks a bit scary.. or is this just telling the hardware "at the end of the bracket clean up and close the door behind you" without affecting other objects?

Comment: It's very strange to me that autoreleasepool helps in this case, because it should release "at the end of the block", that is in your case after it ran the whole decoding. Even the bug that talks about this leak in JSONDecoder still gives the example of a loop: https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-5501. So it's pretty clear how autoreleasepool helps there, but on single decoding... how does it even help? Very strange.
Also good idea to try to test that memory spike on `release` config, as optimizations affect the memory spikes a lot.

Comment: I maybe should've clarified that `.jsonData()` is a helper function for `.toJSONString()` so in a way it does run in the loop. Thanks to your advice I have now ran all 3 combinations in `release` config and indeed it does not matter where I put it, it helps the same way either way, 1) in the extension, 2) in the loop. When I remove them however, even in `release` I have a much higher memory usage. I want to thank you for reminding me to also test in `release` config, I totally missed that and I will keep this in mind for future tests since like you say it could differ

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Autorelease Pools](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmAutoreleasePools.html) are a mechanism which comes from Objective-C for helping automate memory management and ensure that objects and resources are released "eventually", where that "eventually" comes when the pool is [*drained*](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsautoreleasepool/1520553-drain). i.e., an autorelease pool, once created on a thread, captures (retains) all objects which are [`-autorelease`ed](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1571951-autorelease) while the pool is active — when the pool is drained, all of those objects are released. (Note that this is a Foundation feature in conjunction with the Objective-C runtime, and is not directly integrated with hardware: it's way, *way* higher-level than that.)

As a short-hand for managing autorelease pools directly (and avoiding creating [`NSAutoreleasePool`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsautoreleasepool) instances directly), Objective-C introduced the `@autoreleasepool` language keyword, which effectively creates an autorelease pool at the beginning of the scope, and drains it at the end:

```
@autoreleasepool /* create an autorelease pool to capture autoreleased objects */ {
    // ... do stuff ...
} /* release the autoreleasepool, and all objects that were in it */
```

Introducing autorelease pools *manually* in this way grants you more control over when autoreleased objects are effectively cleaned up: if you know that a block of code creates many autoreleased objects that really don't need to outlive that block of code, that may be a good candidate for wrapping up in an `@autoreleasepool`.

---

Autorelease pools pre-date ARC, which automates reference counting in a deterministic way, and its introduction made autorelease pools became largely unnecessary in most code: if an object can be deterministically retained and released, there's no need to rely on autoreleasing it "at some point". (And in fact, along with regular memory management calls like `-retain` and `-release` themselves, ARC will not allow you to call `-autorelease` on objects directly either.)

Swift, following the ARC memory management model, also does not rely on autoreleasing objects — all objects are deterministically released after their last usage. However: Swift does still need to interoperate with Objective-C code, and notable, *not* all Objective-C code (including a lot of code in, e.g., Foundation) uses ARC. Many internal Apple frameworks still use Objective-C's manual memory management, and thus still rely on autoreleased objects.

On platforms where Swift might need to interoperate with Objective-C code, no work needs to be *explicitly* done in order to allow autoreleased objects to eventually be released: every Swift application on Darwin platforms has at least one implicit autorelease pool at the root of the process which captures autoreleased objects. However, as you note: this "eventual" release of Objective-C objects might keep memory usage high until the pool is drained. To help alleviate that high memory usage, Swift has `autoreleasepool { ... }` (matching Objective-C's `@autoreleasepool { ... }`), which allows you to explicitly and *eagerly* capture those autoreleased objects, and free them at the end of the scope.

To answer your questions directly, but in reverse order:

1. *Can I mess up anything using autoreleasepool?* For correctly-written code, **no**. All you're doing is helping the Objective-C runtime clean up these objects a little bit earlier than it would otherwise. And it's critical to note: the objects will only be *released* by the pool — if their retain count is still positive after the pool releases them, they must *still be in use* somewhere, and will *not* be deallocated until that other owner holding on to the object also releases them.

   Is it possible that the introduction of an autoreleasepool will cause some unexpected behavior to occur which didn't before? Absolutely. Incorrectly-written code could have accidentally worked due to the fact that an object was *incidentally* kept alive long enough to prevent unintentional behavior from occurring — and releasing the object sooner might trigger it. But, this is both *unlikely* (given the miniscule amount of actually manual memory management outside of Apple frameworks) and not something you can rely on: if the code misbehaves inside of a newly-introduced `autoreleasepool`, it wasn't correct to begin with, and could have backfired on you some other way.
2. *Does autoreleasepool come with a CPU overhead?* Yes, and it is likely vanishingly small compared to the actual work an application performs. But, that doesn't mean that sprinkling `autoreleasepool` all over the place will be useful:

   - Given the decreasing amount of autoreleased objects in a Swift project as increasing amounts of code transition away from Objective-C, it's becoming rarer to see large numbers of autoreleased objects which need to be eagerly cleaned up. You *could* sprinkle `autoreleasepool`s everywhere, but it's entirely possible that those pools will be *entirely empty*, with nothing to clean up
   - *`autoreleasepool`s don't affect native Swift allocations*: only Objective-C objects can be autoreleased, which means that for a good portion of Swift code, `autoreleasepool`s are entirely wasted

---

So, when *should* you use `autoreleasepool`s?

1. When you're working with code coming from Objective-C, which
2. You've *measured* to show that is contributing to high memory usage thanks to `autorelease`d objects, which
3. You've also *measured* are cleaned up appropriately by the introduction of an `autoreleasepool`

In other words, *exactly* what you've done here in your question. So, kudos.

However, try to avoid cargo-culting the insertion of `autoreleasepool`s all over the place: it's highly unlikely to be effective without actual measurements and understanding what might be going on.

[An aside: how do you know when objects/code might be coming from Objective-C? You can't, very easily. A good rule of thumb is that many Apple frameworks are still written in Objective-C under the hood, or may at some layer return an Objective-C object bridged (or not) to Swift — so they may be a likely culprit to investigate *if you've measured something actionable.* 3rd-party libraries are also much less likely to contain Objective-C these days, but you may also have source access to them to confirm.]

---

Another note about optimizations and `autoreleasepool`s: in general, you should not typically expect a Release configuration of a build to behave differently with regard to autoreleased objects as opposed to a Debug configuration.

Unlike ARC code (both in Swift and in Objective-C), where the compiler can insert memory management optimizations for code *at compile time*, autorelease pools are a runtime feature, and since *any* retain will necessarily keep an object instance alive, even a single insertion of an object into an autorelease pool will keep it alive until it is disposed of *at runtime*. So, even if the compiler can aggressively optimize the specific locations of retains and releases for most objects in a Release configurations, there's nothing to be done for an object that's autoreleased.

(Well, the ARC optimizer can do *some* amount of optimization around autoreleasing objects if it has enough visibility into all of the code using the object, the context of the autorelease pools it belongs to, etc., but this is usually *very* limited because the scope in which the object was originally `-autorelease`d is usually far from the scope in which the autorelease pool lives, by definition [otherwise it would be a candidate for regular memory management].)

Comment: This is easily one of the best answer I have ever seen in an SO post. Thank you so much for your time, you now make me feel like an expert on the topic. I wish SO had a "follow" feature so I could learn and upvote your future posts, thank you so much

Comment: @user2875404 So happy to have helped!