# memory leak from NSString→const char* conversion in Objective C

Tags: objective-c

In [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76140643/1502538) I asked as an aside, for confirmation that my use of `NSString`→`const char*` in the code below is correct. I was asked to remove this as two questions were being asked in a single post.

The code that I have below works, but I can see that memory consumption grows monotonically, so I am concerned about a memory leak. Attempting to `free` the strings results in "pointer being freed was not allocated"; no experience in Objective C, but this segfault seems like the correct behaviour, so where is the leak?

```
#include <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>
#include <CoreGraphics/CGWindow.h>

struct details {
   int wid;
   int pid;
   const char* name;
   const char* window;
};

int activeWindow(struct details *d)
{
    if (d == NULL) {
        return 0;
    }
    NSArray *windows = (NSArray *)CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo(kCGWindowListExcludeDesktopElements|kCGWindowListOptionOnScreenOnly,kCGNullWindowID);
    for(NSDictionary *window in windows){
        int WindowLayer = [[window objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGWindowLayer] intValue];
        if (WindowLayer == 0) {
            d->wid = [[window objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGWindowNumber] intValue];
            d->pid = [[window objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGWindowOwnerPID] intValue];
            d->name = [[window objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGWindowOwnerName] UTF8String];
            d->window = [[window objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGWindowName] UTF8String];
            return 1;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Besides my answer below — I'm assuming this code is using automatic reference counting (ARC), but if for some reason not: `CGWindowListCopyWindowInfo` returns an allocated array which you would also need to `-release`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under the hood, `NSString`s have three main possible representations:

1. A "typical" `NSString` with UTF-16 backing
2. An `NSString` with ASCII backing
3. A tagged pointer string with encoded backing

The specifics of these representations isn't terribly important here, except that when you ask for the `-UTF8String` representation of one, it may need to perform some sort of conversion to get you UTF-8 data. In the case of (2), because ASCII is a strict subset of UTF-8, the string is allowed to hand you a pointer to its already-existing underlying storage; but in (1) and (3), the string must allocate space for UTF-8 data, because it doesn't yet exist.

Because the pointer returned to you from `-UTF8String` is a regular old C pointer, there isn't any lifetime information/management associated with it: the `NSString` can't know when you're "done" using it in order to free the memory. Because the string may also hand you a pointer to its direct underlying storage (and can't communicate to you via this API whether or not you are allowed to free the result or not), `NSString` has to hand you a pointer which you are *never* responsible for freeing.

So there's a bit of a conundrum here:

- `NSString` may need to allocate memory to store UTF-8 data
- `NSString` must hand you a pointer to that data, which you are not responsible for freeing
- `NSString` can't know when you might be done using the pointer, so it can't free it prematurely
- `NSString` *shouldn't* just leak the memory

The way this is handled is by allocating a block of memory which is then [`-autorelease`d](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/1418956-nsobject/1571951-autorelease). You can read more about autorelease pools in the old ["Advanced Memory Management Programming Guide"](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/MemoryMgmt.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/10000011i) (or a briefer explanation in [another answer of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70050353/swift-risk-in-using-autoreleasepool-cpu-usage/70051512#70051512)), but the gist:

- An object which is autoreleased is placed in an "autorelease pool" for later
- When the pool is "drained", all contained objects are released, and their memory is freed
- Unless you create an autorelease pool yourself, or are in a context which has created a local autorelease pool, there is a global autorelease pool for your process
- The global autorelease pool may only be freed at the end of process execution, so unless you put in extra work, you may see autoreleased objects get "leaked" until then

---

The solution, in your case, comes in two parts.

1. From the "Discussion" section of the `-UTF8String` docs:

   > This C string is a pointer to a structure inside the string object, which may have a lifetime shorter than the string object and will certainly not have a longer lifetime. Therefore, you should copy the C string if it needs to be stored outside of the memory context in which you use this property.

   If you're grabbing the `-UTF8String` and attempting to store it, you must create a copy of it which you can later free yourself; otherwise, if the underlying `NSString` *is* released, you'll be holding on to a dangling pointer
2. If you want to ensure that autoreleased objects get cleaned up sooner, you can create a local autorelease pool which will clean them up; in your case, you can do this once per loop

For example:

```objectivec
// This will create an autorelease pool local to this scope.
// At the end of the scope, all autoreleased objects will be cleaned up.
@autoreleasepool {
    d->wid = [[window objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGWindowNumber] intValue];
    d->pid = [[window objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGWindowOwnerPID] intValue];

    const char *ownerName = [[window objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGWindowOwnerName] UTF8String];
    d->name = strdup(ownerName); // Or copy however you'd prefer

    const char *windowName = [[window objectForKey:(NSString *)kCGWindowName] UTF8String];
    d->window = strdup(windowName);
    return 1;
}
```

Later, you will need to make sure you `free(d->name)` and `free(d->window)` or else you'll really be leaking memory.

Comment: Thanks. That has lead me the right direction (nice answer). I found that I also need to `CFRelease(windows);` before return.